# Generic Protocol with Associated Type Not Defining Implicitly

Tags: ios, swift, generics, protocols, associated-types

I'm trying to implicitly define an associated type however I get an error:

> 'RowProtocol' is ambiguous for type lookup in this context

```
protocol RowProtocol {
    associatedtype T
    var cellClass: T.Type { get }
    init(cellClass: T.Type)
}

struct Row: RowProtocol {
    let cellClass: T.Type
    init(cellClass: T.Type) {
        self.cellClass = cellClass
    }
}
```

You could then initialize it using:

```
let implicitRow = Row(cellClass: Cell.self)
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: You need to map `T` to something

Answer (score 0):

Conformance to `RowProtocol` requires mapping the associated type `T` to a concrete type, and `Row` doesn't do this. I assume you also want to make `Row` generic, this is why you didn't specify a type alias for `T` from the protocol.

The solution is to make `Row` generic also:

```
struct Row<T>: RowProtocol {
    let cellClass: T.Type
    init(cellClass: T.Type) {
        self.cellClass = cellClass
    }
}
```

Now the compiler is happy, as it has a concrete type to pass to `RowProtocol`. Keep in mind though that for the compiler the `T` from `Row` is different from the `T` of `RowProtocol`, the latter being a protocol requirement while the first being a generic.

```
// exactly the same struct, but with different name for the generic argument.
struct Row<U>: RowProtocol {
    let cellClass: U.Type
    init(cellClass: U.Type) {
        self.cellClass = cellClass
    }
}
```